# Low beams don't work on VW Golf MK3

Tags: electrical, vw, headlight, golf, fuse

On my **1996 Golf MK3**, the **low beams stopped working**.

I checked the **fuses**, that's not it (swapped 1 & 2, low beams, for 11 & 12, high beams).

I wiggled the ignition switch and the headlights didn't flicker.

It seems **very unlikely** that both bulbs went out at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

**It was the bulbs.** I have read of the same phenomenon on other sites -- *both* low beams go at the same time.

My theory is that either there is something about the electrical system that causes the second bulb to go once the first is gone, or...

One headlight goes out but you don't notice because you still have one that works.

The second one goes and you notice that both are out and cry "what are the chances?!"

Comment: bear in mind that both bulbs would have been fitted at the same time, and used for the same amount of time - so on average, they ought to fail at the same time - most don't simply because each bulb will last slightly more or less than the average time...